# Integrate mvc application and mojoportal cms

Tags: asp.net-mvc, content-management-system, integration

I have an application made in mvc 2 (this is a private-administrative app) and now I'm working on a public web, so I chose a cms in order to make it easy to administrate for not programmers users.

The CMS I choosed was Mojoportal mainly because It's easy to edit and to make my own modules (and I need to make one).

I my app I have one part which has public and private access (It's like a events calendar that anyone related to my company can edit and the company's users have more privileges)

The problem is how to integrate both layers, I now it's difficult to integrate the mojoportal to an MVC app so what I thought was to make a subfolder inside the mojoportal ("Administration" or something like that) and move the mvc app there.

So, my doubt is: is this a proper solution for this scenario?

I tried to do the test and I moved to a subfolder and it gave me web.config errors, any guide or reference to make this?

If you have any other CMS suggestion please make me know.

Hope I had explained well.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

According to the answer for the same question on mojoportal forum you shoul check the first item in their [Developer FAQ](http://www.mojoportal.com/developer-faq.aspx). It contains brief explanation and link for further details.